# Play time event

Tags: android, events, media-player

I know that i can catch events of start, prepare, error and complete of a multimedia file, but i don't know how to catch events like 25% played or something similar without use timers that divide the duration of multimedia file, because the user could pause the play. Is it posible?

Thanks!

***EDITED BELOW***

Finally i had used timers that they do wait and notify when the user click on play/pause but for other developers, there's the explanation of my first idea.

This is the code i've used to throw an event when the player was played the 25%, 50% or 75%. (the code of TaskQ2 and Q3 is practicaly same changing few things) But what i am looking for is to use something similar to mVideoView.setOnPercentPlay(new OnPercentPlay (), percent{/*code*/}); that it was already made on some library os android.

```
int time = Integer.parseInt(ad.getDuracion());
TimerTask taskQ1 = new TimerTask() {
public void run() {
mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
public void run() { 
    if (vv.isPlaying()) {
       String Q1 = mList.getQ1();   
       ping(Q1);
    }
}});}};

    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(taskQ1, time/4*1000 );
    timer.schedule(taskQ2, time/2*1000 ); 
    timer.schedule(taskQ3, time/4*3*1000 );
```

Comment: Can you post some code to show us what you've tried?